# Downgrading gcc-7 to 7.4.0

Tags: apt, downgrade

Is it possible/easy to downgrade the gcc version in Ubuntu 18.04 from 7.5.0 to 7.4.0?

The reason why I want that is because 7.5.0 introduced a [new bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94270) that is making my life more difficult than it should. In the main repository I can only find 7.3.0, but I know 7.4.0 was available at some point because I have it in some docker images where it was installed with `apt`.

So, is there some (un)official repository that holds copies of previous versions of the package?

Comment: This may be useful: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Looks like you can download it from https://reposcope.com/package/gcc-7-multilib-powerpc-linux-gnu  It also looks like 7.4.0 was in the repos for 18.10 and 19.04 which are both EOL.